# Python: tkinter delete object from class and make it invisible

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, widget

I would like to delete an object from another class and make it invisible.

For example a class with a button called Button 1.
Another class with a button called Button 2.

When I click on Button 2 I don't want to see Button 1.

```
from tkinter import*

class Menu(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,bg = "white")
        self.grid()
        self.button_clicks = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self)
        self.button["text"] = "Button 1: 0"
        self.button["command"] = self.update_count
        self.button.grid(ipadx = 5, padx = 150)

    def update_count(self):
        self.button["text"] = "Another try: " + str(self.button_clicks)
        self.button_clicks += 1
        if self.button_clicks > 10:
            self.button_clicks  = 0


class noMenu(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master,bg = "white")
        self.grid()
        self.button_clicks = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button = Button(self)
        self.button["text"] = "Bye button 1"
        self.button["command"] = self.byeMenu
        self.button.grid(ipadx = 5, padx = 150)

    def byeMenu(self):
        Menu.grid_forget()

app = Tk()
app.configure(background= "white")
app.title("Button on my but")
app.geometry("400x200")
first = Menu(app)
second = noMenu(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want widgets to interact use the fact that they have common ancestry to achieve this.  Then if you want a widget to "disappear" you can do so with the geometry manger you are using

An example to work from might be:

```
import Tkinter

class Main(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.first = Menu(self)
        self.second = noMenu(self)

    def first_button_response(self):
        self.first.button.pack_forget()

class noMenu(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(
            self, text="Bye button 1", command=parent.first_button_response
        )
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()

class Menu(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.button = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Button 1")
        self.button.pack()
        self.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Here I used `pack_forget` to remove the first button.  If you want to use the grid manager you should look into `grid_remove` or `grid_forget` depending on whether you want to at some point have the button reappear or not.

Comment: Thanks 
I don't have enough reputation to like your answer.
I like your answer.

Comment: Plus one for helping him.